# Why does automatic scaling behave as it does in Plot?

Tags: plotting

The following command

```
Plot[Exp[-(x^2)], {x, -5, 5}]
```

draws

[image]

while the following command

```
Plot[Exp[-2 (x^2)], {x, -5, 5}]
```

draws

[image]

I.e. the scale is changing which seems unexpected.

Comment: Try `PlotRange->All`.

Comment: "reversed against expected" what do you mean by that?

Comment: Mathematica is trying to identify a region of interest. Here, compared to your `PlotRange` the Peak is too narrow and `Plot` decides to truncate the y-`PlotRange`. Try `Plot[Exp[-2 (x^2)], {x, -3, 3}]` instead.

Comment: @MarkusRoellig please post an answer with this.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem arises from having chosen such a broad x range in your second case. If want to focus on the peak, plot a narrower range around it. For example

```
Plot[Exp[-2 (x^2)], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image: plot.png]